# iOS7: How to create a simple animation?

Tags: xcode, animation, ios7

I was wondering how to build/import an animation in XCode? Do I really need to use SpriteKit? Is there a simple/lightweight solution?

This is my animation (build in Flash) 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/829184/loading_gabel.swf

Comment: UIAnimation should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use SpriteKit. You can stick with UIAnimation because all you are trying to achieve is rotating the image certain degrees at certain intervals.

Comment: Can i export degrees at certain intervals from flash to xcode?

Comment: As images? Yes! For example, import 5 different images into xcode all at different angles then you can use UIAnimation to change the image to look like its rotating...